Extract result of Reap in a natural way no matter if it's empty
This feature has long troubled me, I would like to share it.
If Reap has non-empty set of sown, result looks like:
res = Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e]
{e, {{a, c, d}}}

If there was no any Sow we have:
res = Reap[e]
{e, {}}

I'd like to assign resulting list of sown values to a new variable,
even it is empty.
Natural way
newList = res[[2,1]]

not work in second case, we have error:
Part 1 of {} does not exist

so we need some conditional:
newList = If[res[[2]]!={},res[[2,1]],{}]

Is there a way to make it smarter?
UPD
Thanks to all for cool answers, so I'm confused to choose single one

Using the second argument of First:
First[Reap[a][[2]],{}]
(* {} *)


This only works in versions later than 10.2

Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e, {_}, Splice[#2] &][[2, 1]]

(* {a, c, d} *)

Reap[e, {_}, Splice[#2] &][[2, 1]]

(* {} *)

Original Answer
Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e, {_}, Delete[#2, 0] &][[2, 1]]

(* {a, c, d} *)


Reap[e, {_}, Delete[#2, 0] &][[2, 1]]
   
(* {} *)


This approach should be useful in some conditions, thank you!

Rather than make assumptions about structure, I'd recommend building in your updating process to the Reap explicitly. Here are a couple of ways:
1. Use tags and a function to clearly organize the results:
{res, reaped} = Reap[Sow[a, "newList"]; b; Sow[c, "otherList"]; Sow[d, "newList"]; e, _, Rule]
(* {e, {"newList" -> {a, d}, "otherList" -> {c}}} *)

Now you can extract whatever you need with some simple pattern matching or whatever.
FilterRules[reaped, "newList"]
(* {"newList" -> {a, d}} *)

"newList" /. reaped
(* {a, d} *)

Query["newList"][reaped]
(* {a, d} *)

This approach gives you more semantic clarity in the case when nothing is reaped.
{res, reaped} = Reap[e, _, Rule]
(* {e, {}} *)

FilterRules[reaped, "newList"]
(* {} *)

"newList" /. reaped
(* "newList" *)

Query["newList"][reaped]
(* Missing["PartInvalid", "newList"] *)

If Rule doesn't fit your situation, you can obviously come up with whatever other representation that you want.
2. Perform the assignment as a side-effect:
newList = {};
Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e, _, (newList = #2) &]
(* {e, {{a, c, d}}} *)

newList
(* {a, c, d} *)

newList = {};
Reap[e, _, (newList = #2) &]
(* {e, {}} *)

newList
(* {} *)


If you just want to make a list of sown values, how about using Flatten?
res = Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e];
Flatten[Last[res]]
(* {a, c, d} *)

res = Reap[e];
Flatten[Last[res]]
(* {} *)


It's worked code-golf style which I like, thanks!

But! There is a pitfall. I need to sow 2D points, so single Flatten works not correct,
we should use Flatten[...,1]

A data-set-like approach:
res = Reap[Sow[a, "X"]; b; Sow[c, "X"]; Sow[d, "X"]; e, _, Rule];
newX = Lookup[Last@res, "X", {}]
(* {a, c, d} *)

res = Reap[a; b; c; d; e, _, Rule];
newX = Lookup[Last@res, "X", {}]
(* {} *)

Oh. I just noticed @leric's is half-similar. Anyway, I remember reading on this site a recommendation to always use tags with Sow/Reap (and Throw/Catch, too).

How about defining a helper function?:
Clear[fix];
fix[{a_, {b_List}}] := {a, b}
fix[expr_] := expr

Usage:
{res1, reaped1} = fix@Reap[e];
res1
(* e *)

reaped1
(* {} *)

{res2, reaped2} = fix@Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e];
res2
(* e *)

reaped2
(* {a, c, d} *)


@xzcd, This is good example of right functional code style, thank you!

Sow the magic disappearing list element Nothing as the first thing in the Reap block:
Reap[Sow[Nothing]; e]
(* {e, {{}}} *)


Finally it may be simplest solution without any additional assumptions!
